# TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined while using angular custom directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Browser tells type error replace function while using angular directive.

HTML :

Directives : 
finalize_messaging.directive('format', ['$filter', function ($filter) {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            if (!ctrl) return;

```
        ctrl.$formatters.unshift(function (a) {
            var plainNumber = ctrl.$modelValue.replace(/[^\d|\-+|\.+]/g, '');
            return $filter(attrs.format)(plainNumber,"",0)
        });

        elem.bind('keypress keyup blur', function(event) {
        //      elem.val((elem.val().replace(/[^\d].+/, "")));
        // var charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode
        // if (charCode > 31 && charCode != 46 && charCode != 37 &&
        //     charCode != 39 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        //     return false;
        var plainNumber = elem.val().replace(/[^\d|\-+|\.+]/g, '');
        elem.val($filter(attrs.format)(plainNumber,"",0));
        // return true;

        });

    }
};
```

}]);

Error shows in this Sentence " var plainNumber = ctrl.$modelValue.replace(/[^\d|-+|.+]/g, '');"

Is anything did wrong
Verified a lot.
Can't able to clear can any one help onthis.

Comment: is $modelValue a string?

Comment: maybe initially modelValue is null or undefined... so you can wrap all in an if statement

Comment: Can u please share the code @shall